# Terragrunt - Unsupported attribute --- but tfstate has the attribute

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terragrunt

I cannot figure this out, it's happened a couple of times and this time I'm unable to work around it.

The error I'm getting from terragrunt is

> terragrunt.hcl:25,47-50: Unsupported attribute; This object does not have an attribute named "id".

My issue is that the id which I'm trying to reference is present in the tfstate, why can it not see it?

Shortened code below
terragrunt.hcl

```
dependency "vm01" {
  config_path = "../vm01"
}

include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

terraform {
  source = "//core/azurerm_virtual_machine_extension"
}

locals {
  vm_name = "vm01"
}

inputs = {
  name                  = local.vm_name
  virtual_machine_id    = dependency.vm01.id
.....
}
```

output.hcl

```
output "id" {
  value = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
}
```

tfstate pulled directly from backend storage account

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "0.14.7",
  "serial": 4,
  "lineage": "abcde-guid-abcde",
  "outputs": {
    "id": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/abcde-guid-abcde/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm01",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
...........
}
```

Comment: terragrunt output also shows id and virtual_machine_id as useable outputs on vm01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to yorinasub17 over at the [terraform github](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/1589) I found my answer.

> The outputs are nested under outputs, so the path to id is
> dependency.vm01.outputs.id, not dependency.vm01.id as you are
> referencing in the code snippet. See the [dependency block
> reference](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#dependency) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66669944/15648070) is correct for this situation, it can also happen due to output not being available:

In your `../vm01` dependence you need to `terragrunt refresh` first in order to reflect the output in remote state. After this, it will be available and work when running commands locally.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Important to navigate to the correct directory. Alternatively, one could run 'terragrunt run-all refresh' to have all directories refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Another one of the idiosyncrasies of terragrunt. Let’s say you source a module which did not have the output and you are using remote state, and you are running the executions in a CI/CD platform like Github Actions, which updated the remote state.

Then at a later point, you add the output to the original module. You might think since you are sourcing the updated version of the module, e.g. using git tags, it would recognize the outputs. But it won’t if you are using remote state in an s3 bucket, for example. If you run terragrunt apply, instead of terragrunt plan, then it will update the remote state.

This is one of the plethora of gotchas of terragrunt.